# React modal not displaying

Tags: reactjs

I have attached my main code below. Basically when the page displays and I hit the delete button, no modal pops up. I'm not seeing any compiling error but the dev console shows the following:

```
Warning:React.createElement: type is invalid--expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in. Check your code at ModalItem.js:27, ModalItem.js 26.
```

Here are my code:
ModalItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Item Service from './ItemService';
    class Modal extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addItemService = new ItemService();
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {  //this is showing error at the curly bracket. unexpected token. not sure whats wrong here
        event.preventDefault();
        this.addItemService.deleteData(this.props.obj._id);
      }
      render() {
        // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
        if (!this.props.show) {
          return null;
        }
        else {
          return (
            <div className="static-modal">
              <Modal.Dialog>
                <Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Title>Ready to Delete Student</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this Student?</Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger" />
                  </form>

                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal.Dialog>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
    }
    }

    export default Modal;
```

TableRow.js

```
class TableRow extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.addItemService = new ItemService();
      this.state = {isOpen: false}; 
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj._id}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.item}
          </td>
          <td>
          <Link to={"/edit/"+this.props.obj._id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
        </td>
          <td>
          <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
            Delete
          </button>
            <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
            onClose={this.toggleModal}>
            </Modal>

          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default TableRow;
```

index.js

```
import App from './App';
import AddItem from './components/AddItem';
import IndexItem from './components/IndexItem';
import EditItem from './components/EditItem';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/add-item' component={AddItem} />
        <Route path='/index' component={IndexItem} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' component={EditItem} />
      </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and what this error means?

Comment: Hi,

In your file ModalItem.js you use different components in your render function that don't exist (Modal.Dialog, Modal.Header,...), change them with some divs for a test

And in the file TableRow.js you do not import the Modal component

Comment: The code as is won't compile. You have a trailing closing bracket in ModalItem.js . Also I'm pretty sure Item Service should be one word. also as Jawbonewalk said, you do need to import Modal from somewhere if you're going to use Modal.Dialog, Modal.Header, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments you probably didn't import necessary components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ItemService from './ItemService';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-boostrap' // or reactstrap?
```